# SELECT or PERFORM in a PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, select-into

I have this function in my database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "insertarNuevoArticulo"(nombrearticulo character varying, descripcion text, idtipo integer, idfamilia bigint, artstock integer, minstock integer, maxstock integer, idmarca bigint, precio real, marcastock integer)
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    articulo "Articulo"%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO articulo FROM "Articulo" WHERE "Nombre" = $1 AND "idTipo"=$3 AND "idFamilia"=$4;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO "Articulo" ("Nombre", "Descripcion", "idTipo", "idFamilia", "Stock", "MinStock", "MaxStock") Values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7);
        SELECT last_value
        INTO articulo."idArticulo"
        FROM "public"."Articulo_idArticulo_seq";
    END IF;
    SELECT * FROM "ArticuloMarca" AS am WHERE am."idArticulo" = articulo."idArticulo" and am."idMarca" = $8;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        Insert into "ArticuloMarca"("idArticulo", "idMarca", "PrecioReferencial", "Stock") Values (articulo."idArticulo", $8, $9, $10);
        RETURN TRUE;
    END IF;
    RETURN FALSE;
END;
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
 COST 100;
 ALTER FUNCTION "insertarNuevoArticulo"(character varying, text, integer, bigint, integer, integer, integer, bigint, real, integer)
 OWNER TO postgres;
```

But as soon as I try to use it, it says I need to use `PERFORM` if I want to discard the results! The problem here is that I don't want to! I want them in the `articulo` row I declared!

I'm using this statement:

```
SELECT "insertarNuevoArticulo"('Acetaminofen', 'caro', '1' , '1', '8', '1', '10', '1', '150.7', '10');
```

And the error i get is 42601, a syntax error! How could it be if I'm using the IDE to create it? Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In plpgsql code, `SELECT` without a target triggers an error. But you obviously do *not* want `SELECT INTO`, you just want to set the status of `FOUND`. You would use [**`PERFORM`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) for that.

- [SELECT raises exception in PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230750/select-raises-exception-in-pl-pgsql-function/37234043#37234043)

**Better, yet**, use `IF EXISTS ...`. Consider this rewrite of your function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "insertarNuevoArticulo"( nombrearticulo text, descripcion text, idtipo int, idfamilia bigint, artstock int, minstock int, maxstock int, idmarca bigint, precio real, marcastock int)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _id_articulo "Articulo"."idArticulo"%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT a."idArticulo" INTO _id_articulo
    FROM   "Articulo" a
    WHERE  a."Nombre" = $1 AND a."idTipo" = $3 AND a."idFamilia" = $4;

    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO "Articulo"("Nombre", "Descripcion", "idTipo", "idFamilia", "Stock", "MinStock", "MaxStock")
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
        RETURNING "Articulo"."idArticulo" INTO _id_articulo;
    END IF;

   IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM "ArticuloMarca" a
              WHERE a."idArticulo" = _id_articulo AND a."idMarca" = $8) THEN
      RETURN false;
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO "ArticuloMarca"("idArticulo", "idMarca", "PrecioReferencial", "Stock")
      VALUES (_id_articulo, $8, $9, $10);
      RETURN true;
    END IF;
END
$func$;
```

About `EXISTS`:

- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists-select-into-boolean/11892796#11892796)

The **other major point**:

- Use the [`RETURNING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) of the `INSERT` statement instead of an additional `SELECT`.

#### Postgres 9.5+

In Postgres 9.5 or later use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` (a.k.a. "UPSERT") instead.
You would have `UNIQUE` constraints on `"Articulo"("Nombre", "idTipo", "idFamilia")` and `"ArticuloMarca"("idArticulo", "idMarca")` and then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_new_articulo( nombrearticulo text, descripcion text, idtipo int, idfamilia bigint, artstock int, minstock int, maxstock int, idmarca bigint, precio real, marcastock int)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _id_articulo "Articulo"."idArticulo"%TYPE;
BEGIN
   LOOP
      SELECT "idArticulo" INTO _id_articulo
      FROM   "Articulo"
      WHERE  "Nombre" = $1 AND "idTipo" = $3 AND "idFamilia" = $4;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;

      INSERT INTO "Articulo"("Nombre", "Descripcion", "idTipo", "idFamilia", "Stock", "MinStock", "MaxStock")
      VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
      ON     CONFLICT (tag) DO NOTHING
      RETURNING "idArticulo" INTO _id_articulo;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
   END LOOP;

   LOOP
      INSERT INTO "ArticuloMarca"("idArticulo", "idMarca", "PrecioReferencial", "Stock")
      VALUES (_id_articulo, $8, $9, $10)
      ON     CONFLICT ("idArticulo", "idMarca") DO NOTHING;

      IF FOUND THEN
         RETURN true;
      END IF;

      IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM "ArticuloMarca"
                 WHERE "idArticulo" = _id_articulo AND "idMarca" = $8) THEN
         RETURN false;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

This is faster, simpler and more reliable. The added loops rule out any remaining race conditions with concurrent writes (while adding hardly any cost). Without concurrent writes, you can simplify. Detailed explanation:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)
- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708509/how-to-use-returning-with-on-conflict-in-postgresql/42217872#42217872)

Aside: use legal, lower-case identifiers to avoid all the noisy [double-quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: yeah! thx dude! ill give it a try! this is my first function and theres actually too few examples on the internet! and the documentation is kind of weird, at least to me, im new with all this programing/database stuff! i already solved it but the solution is not good, it does what i want, but im adding stuff im not actually using but to clear the errors. Ill try this! and thx again! :D

Answer (score 4):

This line looks suspicious to me and is probably what is causing your grief:

```
SELECT * FROM "ArticuloMarca" AS am WHERE am."idArticulo" = articulo."idArticulo" and am."idMarca" = $8;
```

You are executing a SELECT within your function, but not doing anything with the results. You need to perform a SELECT INTO like you did earlier in your function.

Comment: yeah! i found i way to debug the function! and i got an error there! i already solved it! was that the 2nd found had like no reference or something like that, well thats what i get from the error message, and solved it adding another variable "Articulo"%rowtype and putting Select * Into thatvariable. Ill give it a try to the first answer! Thx u guys! :D