# PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, exists

I'm writing a function in PL/pgSQL, and I'm looking for the simplest way to check if a row exists.
Right now I'm SELECTing an `integer` into a `boolean`, which doesn't really work. I'm not experienced with PL/pgSQL enough yet to know the best way of doing this.

Here's part of my function:

```
DECLARE person_exists boolean;
BEGIN

person_exists := FALSE;

SELECT "person_id" INTO person_exists
  FROM "people" p
WHERE p.person_id = my_person_id
LIMIT 1;

IF person_exists THEN
  -- Do something
END IF;

END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

*Update* - I'm doing something like this for now:

```
DECLARE person_exists integer;
BEGIN

person_exists := 0;

SELECT count("person_id") INTO person_exists
  FROM "people" p
WHERE p.person_id = my_person_id
LIMIT 1;

IF person_exists < 1 THEN
  -- Do something
END IF;
```

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Simpler, shorter, *faster:* [**`EXISTS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS).

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM people p WHERE p.person_id = my_person_id) THEN
  -- do something
END IF;
```

The query planner can stop at the first row found - as opposed to `count()`, which scans all (qualifying) rows regardless. Makes a big difference with big tables. The difference is small for a condition on a unique column: only one row qualifies and there is an index to look it up quickly.

Only the existence of at least one qualifying row matters. The `SELECT` list can be empty - in fact, that's shortest and cheapest. (Some other RDBMS don't allow an empty `SELECT` list on principal.)

Comment: Good point! (Although person_id is probably the primary key, so it would only "scan" a single table using an index lookup).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: As of now (Postgres 9.1) `count()` *always* triggers a sequential scan. Try `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(id) from tbl` with any table. More on [slow counting in the Postgres Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting). The new index-only scan of Postgres 9.2 are supposed to improve things, because it can (provided some conditions) utilize an index scan for `count(id)` - have yet to try and see it for myself, though ..

Comment: A `count(*)` *with a condition* (especially not on the PK column) will **not** trigger a sequential scan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are right of course! I was thinking of a plain count - as you can see from my example in the comment. I improved my answer with your input, thanks.

Comment: If you want to use this outside of a function the syntax for how to do so is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20957691/908677

Comment: Is there a benefit of `IF EXISTS` over `SELECT ...; IF FOUND ...`? [example for `if found`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/A_Brief_Real-world_Trigger_Example)

Comment: @EugenKonkov: I am leading with that: `Simpler, shorter, faster.`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I'm using PostgreSQL 11.5 and I think we should have a brace to cover EXISTS. Without a brace, the code still run but we can't get `True`. So, the statement should be `IF (EXISTS (SELECT FROM people WHERE person_id = my_person_id)) THEN ...`

Comment: @ThinhPhan: This must be a misunderstanding. Outer parentheses are *not* required. See: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b5759f14378bd04c2bd6dc40424ce2b6)*.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sorry my bad. You are right. It's working now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Would the following be possible?
`DECLARE temperature integer = 0; BEGIN IF EXISTS(SELECT temperature INTO temperature FROM someTable WHERE x=y) THEN DO NOTHING END IF;
`
Would that still fill temperature? If so could you add it to your answer?

Comment: @Splitframe: No, if you `SELECT INTO`, then just check `FOUND`. (It's not allowed in  an `EXISTS` expression.) Also, `SELECT INTO` is only for a single qualifying row, `EXISTS` is for any number of qualifying rows. Consider a new question if anything is unclear ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was under the wrong impression that an empty `SELECT INTO` would trigger an exception. Probably due to some other error I had in the function.  But it just silently fails (or rather successfully returns 0 rows) and, in the above example, temperature just stays 0 which is exactly what I wanted anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Use count(*)

```
declare 
   cnt integer;
begin
  SELECT count(*) INTO cnt
  FROM people
  WHERE person_id = my_person_id;

IF cnt > 0 THEN
  -- Do something
END IF;
```

**Edit** (for the downvoter who didn't read the statement and others who might be doing something similar)

The solution is *only* effective because there is a where clause on a column (and the name of the column suggests that its the primary key - so the where clause is highly effective)

Because of that `where` clause there is no need to use a LIMIT or something else to test the presence of a row that is identified by its primary key. It **is** an effective way to test this.

Comment: Do not use COUNT for this purpose - it is performance issue - or you have to use derived table SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM people LIMIT 1) x

Comment: @PavelStehule: even when there is a `where` condition on the **primary key**? I can't imagine how that would possibly be much slower than your statement. The execution plan is nearly identical for both solutions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name when it filter to PK, then it is ok on 99%. In this case PL/pgSQL should to evaluate 2 SELECTs instead one. But this pattern is just risky. Some people don't do verification so filter is to PK

Comment: @PavelStehule: I added an explanation for this. I compared the plans for Erwin's and mine solution and there is no (real) difference. Due to the `where` on an indexed column this *is* efficient.

Comment: a plan should be same - but PL/pgSQL is just glue for SQL - with count, plpgsql evaluate two SELECTs - 1) SELECT INTO var, 2) SELECT var > 0

Comment: @PavelStehule: are you saying that the `if cnt > 0` is actually running a select statement in the background? And if that is the case wouldn't that be the case with *any* solution - including the "inline" select from Erwin?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, exactly - it is "trivial" SELECT (about 10x faster than normal SELECT), but it is SELECT still. if you like to see real face of plpgsql code, use #option dump -- see first code list from article http://postgres.cz/wiki/PL/pgSQL_efektivn%C4%9B  (sorry, article is in czech, but samples are in English) - http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpostgres.cz%2Fwiki%2FPL%2FpgSQL_efektivn%25C4%259B