# How to check if a row exists in a PostgreSQL stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, exists

I writing a stored procedure in postgres where I need to check if a row exists then act accordingly. something along the line.

```
IF SELECT * FROM foo WHERE x = 'abc' AND y = 'xyz' THEN
  -- do something here
ELSE 
  -- do something else
END;
```

I have googled a bit but got no good hits.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`PERFORM` and the `FOUND` automatic variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html):

```
PERFORM * FROM foo WHERE x = 'abc' AND y = 'xyz';
IF FOUND THEN
    ....
END IF;
```

This will succeed if one *or more* rows is returned. If you want to constrain the result to exactly one row [use `GET DIAGNOSTICS` to get the row count](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS), or use `SELECT INTO` to store the `count(...)` of the rows into a `DECLARE`d variable you then test. If it's an error to get no results, use `SELECT INTO STRICT` to require that *exactly one row* be obtained and stored into the target variable.

Beware of concurrency issues when doing anything like this. If you're attempting to write an upsert/merge function this approach *will not work*. See ["why is upsert so complicated"](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/).

Comment: IS FOUND some implicit variable ? tried to find where it was mentioned in the docs but could not, its too generic a term while searching.

Comment: @ams from the linked page above, "Also, the special variable FOUND is set to true if the query produced at least one row, or false if it produced no rows (see Section 39.5.5)." . See *39.5.5. Obtaining the Result Status*; it's also mentioned elsewhere throughout the "basic statements" page on PL/PgSQL.

Answer (score 30):

Or even simpler with [**`EXISTS`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM foo WHERE x = 'abc' AND y = 'xyz') THEN
    ...
END IF;
```

See:

- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists/11892796#11892796)