# Trigger raising: "ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded"

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am trying to make a trigger where after I insert a painting, then I want to insert it to either the `In_Gallery` table or the `On_Loan` table but not both. When I tried to make a trigger function, I keep getting the error:

> ```
> ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded
> HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
> ```

I am not sure what's wrong with this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkOnLoan()    
    RETURNS trigger AS
$$
    DECLARE    
       countGal numeric;
    BEGIN
            SELECT COUNT(*) INTO countGal FROM IN_GALLERY WHERE P_id = new.P_id;
            IF countGal = 0 THEN    
                INSERT INTO ON_LOAN VALUES (new.Certid, new.P_id, new.Insurer);
            ELSE
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'ALREADY IN GALLERY';
            END IF;
    RETURN new;
    END;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER OnLoan
    AFTER INSERT ON ON_LOAN
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE checkOnLoan();
```

Comment: You have a recursive call. One of your inserts is inserting into a table, which is triggering the trigger, which is inserting into the table, which triggers the trigger... and so on. Each of these layers requires stack space. Eventually, you run out.

Comment: @3Dave Hi thanks for the help, what could I do to get rid of it, my brain is fried been sitting looking at this for the past 4 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `INSERT` again in an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, causing the trigger to be fired again for this second `INSERT` which again `INSERT`s and fires the trigger anew and so on and so on. At some point the stack is exhausted from all that function calls and you get the error.

Remove the `INSERT` from the trigger functions and just `RETURN new`. Returning `new` will cause the original `INSERT` to be completed. There's no need for a manual `INSERT` in the trigger function for `AFTER INSERT` triggers.

Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkOnLoan()    
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
DECLARE    
    countGal numeric;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO countGal FROM IN_GALLERY WHERE P_id = new.P_id;
    IF countGal = 0 THEN    
        RETURN new;
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'ALREADY IN GALLERY';
    END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And analog for the other trigger function.

Comment: It should be noted that `RETURN new;` does not do anything in a row-level `AFTER` trigger.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of you error is an endless loop like the currently accepted answer explained. But you should probably fix more than just that. A `BEFORE` trigger would improve the situation ...

Trigger function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_onloan()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM in_gallery WHERE p_id = NEW.p_id) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'p_id % already in gallery!', NEW.p_id;
   END IF;
   RETURN NEW;  -- for BEFORE trigger
END
$$;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_after_on_loan
BEFORE INSERT ON on_loan             -- !!!
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_onloan();
```

`RETURN NEW` would not make any sense *at all* for an `AFTER` trigger. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html)

> The return value is ignored for row-level triggers fired after an operation, and so they can return `NULL`.

My educated guess: you want a `BEFORE` trigger instead. All that remains to do is raising an exception. It's cheaper to check *before* doing the work than rolling it back later. For the purpose, it's generally more efficient to check for existence with `IF EXISTS ...`  instead of counting. Then you don't need to define any variables and no `DECLARE` section.

Related:

- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists/11892796#11892796)
- [Rollback Transaction on Trigger ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694957/rollback-transaction-on-trigger-error/16701719#16701719)

Obviously, you need another mirrored trigger for table `in_gallery` in this design - which is probably not ideal to begin with.

However you do it, there will be **remaining race condition**. Under concurrent write load, multiple transactions could try to enter the same `p_id` in both tables at virtually the same time, not see the `p_id` in the *other* table, yet, and enter it in *both* tables after all. It helps to keep transactions short to minimize the time frame, but the problem remains in principle.

One clean solution would be a single table `painting` with a `boolean` flag indicating its status. That can only ever have one state at a time. Details depend on your complete situation ...

Aside: reconsider CaMeL case spelling of identifiers in Postgres. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)