# Postgres syntax error at or near "IF"

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

I am new to postgres and I am working on an assignment of mine. I had to create a table with only 1 column and, then I was given this statement to run in on pgadmin III:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1);
SAVEPOINT savepoint1;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2);
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT savepoint1;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (3);
SAVEPOINT savepoint2;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (5);
SAVEPOINT savepoint3;
SELECT * FROM mytable;
--NOTE: You need to run this IF statement as PGScript 
--(button next to the normal run button)
IF (CAST ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable) AS INTEGER) = 4)
BEGIN
      RELEASE SAVEPOINT savepoint2;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(6);
END
--Run the next steps normally
SAVEPOINT savepoint2;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (7);
RELEASE SAVEPOINT savepoint2;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (8);
ROLLBACK TO savepoint2;
COMMIT;
```

when I run this I get this error: syntax error at or near "IF"

I have already take a look at this [38.6.2. Conditionals38.6.2. Conditionals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) , I dont understand this very well, Do I need to change the query to have

```
IF (CAST ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable) AS INTEGER) = 4) THEN 
BEGiN
```

and then when it ends I should end it with:

```
END IF
```

Why there is an error after all??

Comment: You're missing `THEN`... It's `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ...`. You've got `IF ... ... ELSE`.

Comment: @MarcB I tried it with THEN but still I get error

Answer (score 78, accepted):

IF and other PL/pgSQL features are only available inside PL/pgSQL functions. You need to wrap your code in a function if you want to use `IF`. If you're using 9.0+ then you can do use [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) to write an inline function:

```
do $$
begin
  -- code goes here
end
$$
```

If you're using an earlier version of PostgreSQL then you'll have to write a named function which contains your code and then execute that function.

Comment: It wouldn't work in this particular instance, but it's worth mentioning that [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html) behaves like `IF` and is available outside of PL/pgSQL functions. - Just something to consider in these situations.

Answer (score 7):

Not the answer for the OP, but possibly the answer for some who end up here (like myself):
If you DECLARE variables within the BEGIN-END block, you will get the same syntax error.

So this is wrong:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  DECLARE my_var VARCHAR(50) := 'foo';
  IF my_var IS NULL THEN
     --some logic
  END IF;
END; 
$$
```

This should fix it:

```
DO $$
DECLARE my_var VARCHAR(50) := 'foo';
BEGIN
  IF my_var IS NULL THEN
     --some logic
  END IF;
END; 
$$
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me! But how can I learn that... Where did you get it?)