# Postgres: if-else condition depending on prompt, in .sql file called via \i

Tags: postgresql, if-statement, psql, prompt

With Postgres 10.10, here is what I am trying to accomplish. I want to have a `test.sql` script file (executed by `\i /path/test.sql`) whose code execution depends on what the user inputs after an initial prompt.

For instance, with code below I would like some text to be echoed and a table to be created, but the echoed text and the table name should depend on the text passed by the user as input to a prompt:

```
\prompt 'What is your favourite color?' answer
IF ('blue' = :answer) THEN
    \echo 'It is blue! :) '
    CREATE TABLE blue;
ELSE
    \echo 'It is something else. :( '
    CREATE TABLE :answer;
END IF;
```

However, a few errors prevent that from working:

```
myuser=# \i /home/myuser/test.sql
What is your favourite color?red
It is blue! :) 
psql:/home/myuser/test.sql:4: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: IF ('blue' = red) THEN
        ^
It is something else. :( 
psql:/home/myuser/test.sql:7: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ELSE"
LINE 1: ELSE
        ^
psql:/home/myuser/test.sql:8: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: END IF;
            ^
myuser=#
```

Notice that this is not the same as asked in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207666/how-do-i-use-the-input-from-a-prompt-in-a-conditional-if. Also, I tried adapting it to follow the answer in [Postgres syntax error at or near "IF"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957292/postgres-syntax-error-at-or-near-if), but then I just get more errors, starting with "syntax error at or near 'DO'".

Is there a way for me to accomplish this task? That is, every time an user executes the `test.sql` file with `\i`, the user is prompted and the execution of the code within the file branches depending on the text that the user inputed via prompt?

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL. But `psql` offers an `\if` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#PSQL-METACOMMAND-IF

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The only problem is how to convert `answer == 'blue'` into boolean to be used with `\if`. I only see a reference to this type of issue in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207666/how-do-i-use-the-input-from-a-prompt-in-a-conditional-if, but that answer does not help here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT :'answer' = 'blue' AS isblue \gset
\if :isblue
   ...
\endif
```