# How to use a argument from bash call in postgresql script?

Tags: postgresql, bash, if-statement, syntax-error

I have the following bash script call.

```bash
psql -U postgres postgres < ../dump_script.sql -v test=1 >/dev/null
```

In the `dump_script.sql`-script I have the following code:

```sql
\set dbName 'db_dev'

IF :test = 1 THEN
    dbName := 'db_test'
END IF;
```

If I don't use the `test` parameter everything works as expected, the regular dev database is build - if I feed `test` to the script the following error is thrown.

```bash
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: IF 1 = 1 THEN
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: remove ; after BEGIN

Comment: Did not help - I removed the `BEGIN END;` completely because it is no transaction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres syntax error at or near "IF"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957292/postgres-syntax-error-at-or-near-if)

Comment: You are trying to run an SQL command named IF, but there is no such SQL command.  Maybe you want to use the psql metacommand `\if`?

Comment: @jjanes Thank you, this helped. The documentation of the meta-commands could be better or at least easier to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is possible because of the hint from @jjanes

```sql
\set dbName 'dbDev'

SELECT :test = 1 AS is_test_run \gset

\if :is_test_run
    \set dbName 'dbTest'
\endif
```

This works as intended!