# I need some SQL voodoo to prevent two queries: doing an alter or not based on another query's result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following ALTER command:

```
ALTER TABLE exchange.{tableName} SET (timescaledb.compress, timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'ticker', timescaledb.compress_orderby= 'ts desc');
```

It enables compression in TimeScaleDB and is part of a longer query.

If compression was already enabled AND some part of the data was already compressed, then it will return an error.

Now, I can use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timescaledb_information.compression_settings info
WHERE info.hypertable_schema = 'exchange' AND info.hypertable_name = 'trades';
```

To determine if it is already set.

If it returns 0, I can safely run the ALTER, if it returns anything > 0, I should not run it.

Is there a way to build a query where the ALTER would be executed only if the result of the query above is 0? I'm not talking about building external functions, etc, but something that can be done inline.

Comment: Have you looked into using [if..then](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-plpgsql/plpgsql-if-else-statements/)?

Comment: Isn’t it just for procedure? I’m looking for an inline solution in the query itself

Comment: Conditional expressions aren't exclusively for stored procedures. You can just do `if (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM timescaledb_information.compression_settings info
WHERE info.hypertable_schema = 'exchange' AND info.hypertable_name = 'trades') = 0 then (alter table here)`. You could also use a [case statement](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-case/), but it's the same concept.

Comment: This doesn't run as a query: ERROR: syntax error at or near "if"

Comment: Ah ok I guess this is a restriction in PostgeSQL. I had to search really hard to find that for some reason. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20957691/10601203) is a solution I found for PostgreSQL 9,0+ to use it in an inline query.

Comment: And according to a comment on that answer, case statements can be used outside of functions.

Comment: @jesse, I see the idea; can you put together an answer? I'll run the code and confirm it.

Comment: I will in a few hours. At work currently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246083/discussion-between-thomas-and-jesse).