# Can't pass args to `DO $$ ... END $$` function from Golang lib/pq

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have following SQL (PostgreSQL) query:

```sql
DO $$ BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM segment WHERE slug = $1 AND is_active = true) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION $2; 
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO segment (slug) VALUES ($1)
        ON CONFLICT(slug) DO 
            UPDATE SET is_active = true; 
    END IF; 
END $$;
```

If you wondering why I wrapped IF-ELSE statement inside $$ function: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957292/postgres-syntax-error-at-or-near-if).

Now I trying to use it with arguments from Golang using `database/sql` and `github.com/lib/pq`:

```golang
_, err := p.Exec(`
    DO $$ BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM segment WHERE slug = $1 AND is_active = true) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION $2; 
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO segment (slug) VALUES ($1)
            ON CONFLICT(slug) DO 
                UPDATE SET is_active = true; 
        ND IF; 
    END $$;`,
slug,
exceptionMsg,
)
```

But when I run this then I got error with following message:

```
pq: got 2 parameters but the statement requires 0
```

Looks like sql-driver doesn't recognize argument placeholders inside of $$ function.

Firstly I tried use query without $$ function, like so:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM segment WHERE slug = $1 AND is_active = true) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION $2; 
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO segment (slug) VALUES ($1)
    ON CONFLICT(slug) DO 
        UPDATE SET is_active = true; 
END IF;
```

But I got same error as in [metioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957292/postgres-syntax-error-at-or-near-if):

```
pq: syntax error at or near "IF"
```

---

**UPD.**
I understand that it will be more simple to split this logic into two separate queries and handle it from golang code, but I want to optimize it and use only one query.

Comment: The issue you're facing is due to the fact that the DO block is an anonymous code block and doesn't support parameterized queries in the way you're trying to use them. The DO block treats everything inside as a literal string, so it doesn't recognize the $1 and $2 placeholders.

Comment: That's true. But It will be sad if there are no any workarounds. To me it's a bit strange that it is impossible to use if-else statements without wrapping it into a function...

Comment: First off a `Do` block can **never** receive parameters nor return values except db changes it performs. You could convert this to a plpgsql procedure then call the procedure and pass parameters as needed. However,  what are you attempting to accomplish? Your code will never execute the `on conflict` clause; the `if` statement guarantees you will not get a conflict. Just use the `Insert` without the `Do` block. You only loose the `exception` raised if the slug already exists, but that is what the `on conflict` clause avoids.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by others, the [`DO` code block](https://postgresql.org/docs/15/interactive/sql-do.html) doesn't accept parameters.

> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function **with no parameters**, returning `void`. It is parsed and executed a single time.

So you should either use a pre-declared function or, alternatively, you can use [`WITH` (or CTE)](https://postgresql.org/docs/15/interactive/queries-with.html) to achieve pretty much the same thing.

```sql
WITH x AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM segment
    WHERE slug = $1
    AND is_active
)
INSERT INTO segment (slug)
SELECT $1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM x)
ON CONFLICT (slug)
DO UPDATE SET is_active = true
```

And you can use [`RowsAffected`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.21.0#Result.RowsAffected) to determine if the query was successful (i.e., an insert, or an on-conflict-update occurred).

```golang
res, err := db.Exec(query, slug)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
num, err := res.RowsAffected()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
if num < 1 {
    return errors.New(exceptionMsg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve the problem with a trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dont_update_active() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF OLD.is_active AND NEW.is_active THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'the segment is already active';
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER dont_update_active BEFORE UPDATE OF segment
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION dont_update_active();
```

Then all you have to run is the `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying your code by bringing the positional placeholders outside the dollar quoted block, so you can pass the parameters to your query without having conflicts, something like this;

```
query := `
    DO $$ BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM segment WHERE slug = $1 AND is_active = true) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION $2; 
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO segment (slug) VALUES ($1)
            ON CONFLICT(slug) DO 
                UPDATE SET is_active = true; 
        END IF; 
    END $$;
`

_, err := db.Exec(query,
    slug,
    exceptionMsg,
)
if err != nil {
    // Handle the error
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work and I get the same error