# Drop certain tables in a function managing partitions

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql, partitioning, dynamic-sql

I needed a function to automatically manage partitions in a DB. I found a function that created 2 months at a time and adapted it to work with quarters and multiple tables with different primary keys and creation date keys.
Now I need to change it from dropping the last quarter´s partition. Instead I only want it to drop a quarter´s partitions if they are from the previous year. How do I change the code for previous quarters to do that?

Relevant code:

```
-- check if the partition for the previous quarter exists
v_date_from := date_trunc('quarter', v_current_date - '3 month'::interval);
v_partition_name := master_table || '_Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM v_date_from) || '_' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date_from);
v_rule_name := 'rule_' || master_table || '_Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM v_date_from) || '_' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date_from);

SELECT COUNT(*) = 1 INTO v_exists FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = v_partition_name;

IF (v_exists) THEN

    EXECUTE 'DROP RULE ' || v_rule_name || ' ON ' || master_table;
    EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || v_partition_name;

END IF;
```

Complete function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION manage_partitions(timestamp without time zone, master_table character varying, prime_key character varying, prime_date character varying) RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

    -- name of the next partition and rule (and interval boundaries)
    v_partition_name    VARCHAR(32);
    v_rule_name         VARCHAR(32);

    v_date_from         TIMESTAMP;
    v_date_to           TIMESTAMP;

    -- current date (if NULL, a current timestamp is used)
    v_date              ALIAS FOR $1;
    v_current_date      TIMESTAMP;

    -- used just for checking existence of the partitions
    v_exists            BOOLEAN;

BEGIN

    IF (v_date IS NULL) THEN
        v_current_date := current_timestamp;
    ELSE
        v_current_date := v_date;
    END IF;

    -- check if the partition for the previous quarter exists
    v_date_from := date_trunc('quarter', v_current_date - '3 month'::interval);
    v_partition_name := master_table || '_Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM v_date_from) || '_' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date_from);
    v_rule_name := 'rule_' || master_table || '_Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM v_date_from) || '_' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date_from);

    SELECT COUNT(*) = 1 INTO v_exists FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = v_partition_name;

    IF (v_exists) THEN

        EXECUTE 'DROP RULE ' || v_rule_name || ' ON ' || master_table;
        EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || v_partition_name;

    END IF;

    -- create a partition for this quarter
    v_date_from := date_trunc('quarter', v_current_date);
    v_date_to := v_date_from + '3 month';
    v_partition_name := master_table || '_Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM v_date_from) || '_' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date_from);
    v_rule_name := 'rule_' || master_table || '_Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM v_date_from) || '_' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date_from);

    SELECT COUNT(*) = 1 INTO v_exists FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = v_partition_name;

    IF (NOT v_exists) THEN

        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || v_partition_name || ' (PRIMARY KEY (' || prime_key || '), CHECK (' || prime_date || ' >= ''' || v_date_from || ''' AND ' || prime_date || ' < ''' || v_date_to || ''')) INHERITS (' || master_table || ')';
        EXECUTE 'CREATE RULE ' || v_rule_name || ' AS ON INSERT TO ' || master_table || ' DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO ' || v_partition_name || ' VALUES (NEW.*)';
        -- if you need to create indexes / foreign keys / whatever on the partition, you may do it here

    END IF;

    -- create a partition for next quarter
    v_date_from := date_trunc('quarter', v_current_date + '3 month'::interval);
    v_date_to := v_date_from + '3 month';
    v_partition_name := master_table || '_Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM v_date_from) || '_' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date_from);
    v_rule_name := 'rule_' || master_table || '_Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM v_date_from) || '_' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date_from);

    SELECT COUNT(*) = 1 INTO v_exists FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = v_partition_name;

    IF (NOT v_exists) THEN

        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || v_partition_name || ' (PRIMARY KEY (' || prime_key || '), CHECK (' || prime_date || ' >= ''' || v_date_from || ''' AND ' || prime_date || ' < ''' || v_date_to || ''')) INHERITS (' || master_table || ')';
        EXECUTE 'CREATE RULE ' || v_rule_name || ' AS ON INSERT TO ' || master_table || ' DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO ' || v_partition_name || ' VALUES (NEW.*)';

        -- if you need to create indexes / foreign keys / whatever on the partition, you may do it here

    END IF;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Comment: You should provide the source where you `found a function that created 2 months at a time` and (as always!) your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the following line:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) = 1 INTO v_exists FROM pg_tables 
WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = v_partition_name;
```

Into something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) = 1 INTO v_exists FROM pg_tables 
WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = v_partition_name 
and v_date_from < date_trunc('year', current_date);
```

This will return `1` only in the case when partition is from previous year.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are working off is **outdated**. It is also rather inefficient for *any* version of Postgres. (I'd be interested where you got that from?)

**Completely rewrite the whole function** with features of modern-day SQL and PL/pgSQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION manage_partitions(
     v_date       timestamp
   , master_table regclass
   , prime_key    text
   , prime_date   text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   v_current_date   timestamp := COALESCE(v_date, now()); -- fallback for NULL
   v_date_from      timestamp;
   v_partition_name text;

BEGIN
   -- drop partition for previous quarter of previous year if exists --
   v_date_from := date_trunc('quarter', v_current_date - interval '3 month');

   IF v_date_from < date_trunc('year', now()) THEN -- your (odd?) condition
      v_partition_name := master_table || to_char(v_date_from, '"_q"Q_YYYY');

      EXECUTE format(
         'DROP RULE  IF EXISTS %I ON %s;
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %I'
        , 'rule_' || master_table || to_char(v_date_from, '"_q"Q_YYYY')
        , master_table
        , v_partition_name);
   END IF;

   -- create partition for this quarter --
   v_date_from := date_trunc('quarter', v_current_date);
   v_partition_name := master_table || to_char(v_date_from, '"_q"Q_YYYY');

   IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM pg_tables t
      WHERE  t.schemaname = 'public'
      AND    t.tablename  = v_partition_name) THEN

      EXECUTE format(
         'CREATE TABLE %$1I (
             PRIMARY KEY (%$2I), CHECK (%$3L >= %$4L AND %$3L < %$5L))
             INHERITS (%$6s);
          CREATE RULE %$7I AS ON INSERT TO %$6s DO INSTEAD
          INSERT INTO %$1I VALUES (NEW.*)'
        , v_partition_name
        , prime_key
        , prime_date
        , v_date_from
        , v_date_from + interval '3 month'
        , master_table
        , 'rule_' || master_table || to_char(v_date_from, '"_q"Q_YYYY')
      );
   END IF;

   -- create partition for next quarter --
   v_date_from := date_trunc('quarter', v_current_date + interval '3 month');
   v_partition_name := master_table || to_char(v_date_from, '"_q"Q_YYYY');

   IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM pg_tables t
      WHERE  t.schemaname = 'public'
      AND    t.tablename = v_partition_name) THEN

      EXECUTE format(
         'CREATE TABLE %$1I (
             PRIMARY KEY (%$2I), CHECK (%$3L >= %$4L AND %$3L < %$5L))
             INHERITS (%$6s);
          CREATE RULE %$7I AS ON INSERT TO %$6s DO INSTEAD
          INSERT INTO %$1I VALUES (NEW.*)'
        , v_partition_name
        , prime_key
        , prime_date
        , v_date_from
        , v_date_from + interval '3 month'
        , master_table
        , 'rule_' || master_table || to_char(v_date_from, '"_q"Q_YYYY')
      );
   END IF;

END
$func$;
```

- You can assign variables at declaration time to simplify code.
- Replace:

  ```
    '_Q' || EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM v_date_from) || '_' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM v_date_from)
  ```

  with the simpler and faster:

  ```
    to_char(v_date_from, '"Q_"Q_YYYY')
  ```

  [`to_char()` in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).
- use the superior for `IF EXISTS (...) THEN ...`. We can then drop the useless variable `v_exists`. See:

  - [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists-select-into-boolean/11892796#11892796)
- Have a look at the manual page on [**`format()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) (Postgres **9.1+**). If you are going to work with dynamic SQL you need to know about it.
- Use the object identifier type `regclass` for `master_table` to verify that it exists and is visible with the current setting for search_path and prevent SQL injection at the same time. See:

  - [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- Don't use [the outdated and discouraged `ALIAS FOR` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ALIAS). Use parameter names instead, like you already do for all other function params.
- Note how I replaced capital letters in identifiers (which are a bad idea) with lower case letters ('Q' -> 'q'). More in the last paragraph of this related answer:

  - [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)
- I also dropped the variables `v_date_to` and `v_rule_name` and replaced them with expressions since those are used once only in my code.