# PL/pgSQL variable percieved as column

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a problem with my Postgres and it looks like a simple one. I have done my research but I have not seen anything similar online and would like some clarification:

This is done inside a function, here is the whole code:

```
BEGIN
    IF($5 IS NOT NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO "PushDevice"("DeviceId","PushNotificationId", "pushId","deviceType",sound)
            SELECT DISTINCT  d.id, $4,d.pushid,d.type,d.sound FROM "Device" d  inner join "DeviceLocation" dl ON  d.id = dl."DeviceId" 
            WHERE dl."FIPScode" in (select "FIPScode" from "CountyFIPS"  where "stateCode"=$5) AND dl."AppId"=$2 AND d.pushId is not null and d.pushId <>'' and d.pushId<>'1234-5678-9101-2345-3456' and d."isTest"=$3 and d."enableNotification"=TRUE and dl."isDeleted"=0
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "PushDevice" t where t."DeviceId"=d.id AND t."PushNotificationId"=$4);
        END;
    ELSE 

        DECLARE "epiCentre" VARCHAR := NULL;
                        magnitude FLOAT = NULL;
        BEGIN
            SELECT polygon INTO "epiCentre" from alert  where id=$1 and "disablePush"=FALSE;
        END;

        IF("epiCentre" IS NOT NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
                INSERT INTO "PushDevice"("DeviceId","PushNotificationId", "pushId","deviceType","sound")
                SELECT DISTINCT  d.id, $4,d."pushId",d.type,d.sound FROM "Device" d  inner join "DeviceLocation" dl   ON  d.id = dl."DeviceId"
                WHERE  dl."AppId"=$2 AND d."pushId" is not null and d."pushId" <>'' and d."pushId" <>'1234-5678-9101-2345-3456' and d."isTest" =$3  and ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_GeometryFromText("epiCentre"), ST_GeometryFromText(geoPoint))<=d.radius * 1609.344 and magnitude>= d.magnitude and d."enableNotification"=1 and dl."isDeleted"=0
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "PushDevice" t where t."DeviceId"=d.id AND t."PushNotificationId"=$4);
        END;
        END IF;

        RETURN QUERY SELECT pd.* FROM  "PushDevice" pd
        WHERE pd."PushNotificationId" =$4 and pd."sentAt" is null;

END IF;
END;
```

The problem is here specifically:

```
DECLARE "epiCentre" VARCHAR := NULL;
                        magnitude FLOAT = NULL;
        BEGIN
            SELECT polygon INTO "epiCentre" from alert  where id=$1 and "disablePush"=FALSE;
        END;

        IF("epiCentre" IS NOT NULL) THEN
```

With error:

```
Procedure execution failed
ERROR:  column "epiCentre" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ("epiCentre" IS NOT NULL)
                ^
QUERY:  SELECT ("epiCentre" IS NOT NULL)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "GetDevicesForPush... line 18 at IF.
```

So somehow the I`F` statement perceives `epiCentre` as column instead of value. And it does not even know it exists although I specifically declared it above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please, *always* include the function header, which is an integral part of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to many `BEGIN-END` statements. The declaration of `epiCentre` is only valid to the first `END`. And the `IF` is after that. Therefore I would use on Block for the whole `ELSE` part.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-structure.html

Comment: IT was close. Note exactly that. I declared the vars as the first statement of my query and it worked. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

As you have found yourself already that [`DECLARE` must be placed before `BEGIN` of a each block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-structure.html).

**More importantly**, you do not need multiple blocks here at all. And you don't need a variable either. Use this simpler, safer and faster form:

```
CREATE function foo(...)
   RETURNS ... AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF($5 IS NOT NULL) THEN
      -- no redundant BEGIN!
      INSERT INTO  ... ;
      -- and no END!
   ELSIF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM alert
                 WHERE  id = $1
                 AND    "disablePush" = FALSE
                 AND    polygon IS NOT NULL   -- only if polygon can be NULL
                ) THEN
      INSERT INTO ... ;

      ...

   END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

More Details:

- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists - SELECT INTO boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists-select-into-boolean/11892796#11892796)