# Use column as schema name in SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, identifier

I know this is a bit of a far-fetched question, but is it in any way possible to do following?

```
select cc.schema,
      (select exists(select * 
                     from (select cc.schema).helpers cs
                     where cs.chain_id=cc.id)
      ) as hasHelpers
from customer.chain cc 
where cc.id=$1
```

What I'm trying to do is convert `cc.schema` to the schema name in the exists statement! Is this possible and how?

If I try to run the statement above I get an error:

> subquery in FROM must have an alias .... from **(select** cc...

Comment: one way is to write a function which will check if shema exists, then if exists with an execute 'select * from ''||$1||''.helpers cs  where cs.chain_id=''$2'')' into ... checks if value is present

Answer (score 0):

You need **dynamic SQL** for this. I suggest a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_chk_schemas(_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE (schema text, schema_exists bool, has_helpers bool) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOR schema, schema_exists, has_helpers IN
      SELECT cc.schema, to_regclass(quote_ident(cc.schema) || '.helpers') IS NOT NULL
      FROM   customer.chain cc
      WHERE  cc.id = $1
   LOOP
      IF schema_exists THEN 
         EXECUTE format('SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM %I.helpers WHERE id = $1)', schema)
         USING $1
         INTO  has_helpers;
      END IF;

      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Related:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)
- [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists - SELECT INTO boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists-select-into-boolean/11892796#11892796)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)