# PostgreSQL IF statement won't accept parameters

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, plpgsql

I'm trying to use PostgreSQL IF sentence and I use `MapSqlParametersSource` to pass parameter to the SQL query. Interesting thing happens that if I pass a parameter to IF condition subquery it won't accept (interpret it properly) it, but if I define value in subquery then it will give me the results. So what I mean is this:

## This works

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("recurr", true);
String sql = "DO " +
"$do$ " +
"BEGIN " +
 "IF (SELECT f.recurring_till FROM FINANCE_ENTITY f WHERE f.recurring = true) THEN SELECT amount, name FROM FINANCE_ENTITY; " +
"END IF; " +
"END " +
"$do$";
getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(sql, params, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(FinanceEntity.class));
```

This return me results successfully.

## This won't work

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("recurr", true);
String sql = "DO " +
"$do$ " +
"BEGIN " +
 "IF (SELECT f.recurring_till FROM FINANCE_ENTITY f WHERE f.recurring = :recurr) THEN SELECT amount, name FROM FINANCE_ENTITY; " +
"END IF; " +
"END " +
"$do$";
getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(sql, params, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(FinanceEntity.class));
```

This will give me always following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.

My question is why I can't pass a parameter to my subquery using `MapSqlParameterSource`?

I use PostgreSQL 9.3.

Answer (score 2):

The problems with parameter passing aside (so this does not directly answer your question) you don't need either a `DO` statement or an `IF` for this. A simple `SELECT` does the job:

```
SELECT amount, name
FROM   FINANCE_ENTITY
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   FINANCE_ENTITY
   WHERE  recurring = $1
   AND    recurring_till
   );
```

More importantly, you cannot return rows from a `DO` statement ***at all***. So your claim *"This return me results successfully"* is ... a surprise to say the least. Because that's *impossible*:

- [How to perform a select query in a DO block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652477/how-to-perform-a-select-query-in-a-do-block/14653151#14653151)
- [PostgreSQL Function PERFORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115806/postgresql-function-perform/10117015#10117015)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact when I use the one that works, I get an error where it says "More than one rows returned". Thus it actually return some rows.

Comment: @AmirAl: No, it does not. That's probably a PL/pgSQL error message (that obviously should be in your question to begin with) complaining that `IF` does not accept expressions returning more than one row. If you fix that, you'll get the next error complaining about the `SELECT` without target. I added some links with more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for those links I will definitely check them.