# FOR loop inside json_build_array() function does not work

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb, generate-series

I am currently working on a function in Postgres. I have the function working, but I need to add a loop inside the `json_build_array()` function to add multiple of what is inside the array. This is what I currently have:

```
select jsonb_build_object('start', jsonb_build_object(
        'inv', json_build_array(
            for i in select * from generate_series(1,5) loop
            jsonb_build_object(...
            end loop
```

But I get an error saying:

> Syntax error at or near "for".

Comment: what you you need the i for?

Comment: That's not valid SQL, so it can't work: FOR does not exits

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have not included the full SQL. I have only included the part where I need some help. This is part of a function that I am working on.

Comment: Post the entire code, not half of it. And the result you're looking for. A loop is something I always try to avoid, in most cases you don't need them

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have added the expected output and have added what I have worked on until now.

Comment: Where should these names come from?

Comment: The variable names and their values are coming from DB.

Comment: I have rolled back to your initial question. Please ask your new question as new question.

Answer (score 1):

The `FOR` loop is a [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) syntax element that is not allowed within an SQL statement (even if that's nested in a PL/pgSQL block).

Your obvious intent can be implemented like this:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_build_object('start', jsonb_build_object(
          'inv', ((SELECT jsonb_agg(some_name)
                   FROM   jsonb_build_object('foo', 1) AS some_name, generate_series(1,5)))));
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nvbqCqbD)

Replace `jsonb_build_object('foo', 1) AS some_name` with the actual object and name you need.

Of course, you have to assign or [return](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) the result in a PL/pgSQL block. See:

- [SELECT or PERFORM in a PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115806/select-or-perform-in-a-pl-pgsql-function/10117015#10117015)

Related:

- [Postgres FOR LOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop/19147320#19147320)

Comment: Your solution works, but I have a question. I checked the values for all the elements inside both the arrays and both arrays have the same value. Is it possible to have different values for both arrays?

Comment: @user2529660: There is only one array. (?) But anything is possible.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There is only 1 array, but there are 2 objects inside that 1 array and I want to know if it is possible to have different values for same variables inside the 2 objects.

Comment: @user2529660 Anything is possible. I suggest you start a new question with the specifics. You can always link to this question for context, but don't change this one after it has been answered.